# Hopf Bifurcation for a non-linear dynamical system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, code-request

I am very new to mathematica and also to **Hopf bifurcation** or any bifurcation for that matter. But I am trying to obtain a **Hopf bifurcation** for a dynamical system. Now, so far, I cannot find any Q&As related to **Hopf Bifurcation** on this site.

The system of equations (1-2)  are shown below

[image]

for which i have coded it as

```
Manipulate[
Module[{nds, c, p}, 
nds =
NDSolve[{c'[t] == (v1 (p[t]/(p[t] + d1))^3 (c[t]/(c[t] + f5))^3 (N_open/N_total)^3)(ctot - (c1 + 1) c[t]) - v3c[t]^2/(k3^2 + c[t]^2),
         p'[t] == v4 (c[t] + (1 - a_lpha) k4/c[t] + k4) - Irp[t]}, {c,p}, {t, 0,100}]]]
```

and the parameters are as follows

[image]

My goal is to obtain the Hopf bifurcation similar to this

[image]

with C and P on the x- and y-axis respectively.

**Can anyone guide me on how to obtain the Hopf Bifurcation. (*Even the text book by Stan Wagon only describes the general Bifurcation*)**

Comment: If `C` and `P` were on the axes then it would be what is called a phase portrait of this dynamical system. A bifurcation diagram on the other hand would have either `C` or `P` on the y axis and a constant on the x axis, all other constants being fixed. The lines would correspond to equilibrium points, i.e. roots of the right hand side of the dynamical system. Please check your source again to find out what the axes represent and also please write out the equations in *Mathematica* syntax.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for the reply. I checked the source and the axes are as I have mentioned them. Solid line indicates stable steady states, dashed indicates unstable steady states, and dashed-dotted line gives the maximum and minimum. The system generates oscillations of C (variations in C's concentrations to be precise) with either a fixed P or a range of P. The bifurcation diagrams shows us the range of P that allows the oscillations to occur. Also like I said I am new to mathematica so it will take me some time to write down the ODEs in Mathematica syntax.

Comment: You may do several things about it with Mma, but first of all you surely should learn, what is the Hopf bifurcation. There are lots of sources.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes I am reading several materials on Hopf Bifurcation.

Comment: Try your question on [Math.se].  Also, note that the static equilibrium is unstable where the Hopf oscillatory solution exists.

Comment: If you wish to solve this problem with Mathematica, please write it in Mathematica format and define all quantities.  As it stands, many symbols are undefined.  Once that is done, use `ParameticNDSolveValue` with a suitably selected parameter.

Comment: @bbgodfrey So am I wrong in what I wrote? `NDSolve` will calculate trajectories, yes, but the Hopf bifurcation (and the bifurcation diagram) is about how the number of equilibrium points and their stabilities change over time. He shouldn't have to solve the system to see that, finding the roots and the eigenvalues of the system should be enough. (And yes, I know that the OP said that `P` and `C` are on the axes which would mean that it shows trajectories, but I don't believe that's right. This looks very much like a bifurcation diagram to me, with dotted lines for unstable equilibriums.)

Comment: Have a look here [mathematica hopf bifurcation](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=RPGTVonAAseX8Qf8nJyoAQ&gws_rd=ssl,cr&fg=1#q=mathematica+hopf+bifurcation) there are about 22900 hits.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the information. But the reason I put the questions here was to understand how to code it in Mathematica. I will try and repost the question like you said.

Comment: @Pickett How do I just find the roots and the eigen values (pardon my ignorance on using Mathematica). And yes the dotted lines are unstable states and the dashed-dotted lines are unstable steady states(Oscillations).

Comment: @Louis I am sorry but I do not find anything useful

Comment: Guys please be patient. I will try my best to modify the question as per the norms of the page.